# Resource not found for the segment 'me'

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

i'm using Graph API to retrieve profile information of user who's currently logged in from the Azure AD, unfortunately i'm receiving the following error message : 
**{"odata.error":{"code":"Request_ResourceNotFound","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Resource not found for the segment 'me'."}}}**

Below is my code :

```
Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(serviceRootURL);
ActiveDirectoryClient adClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(
                serviceRoot,
                async () => await GetAppTokenAsync());

var user = (User)await adClient.Me
            .Expand(x => x.Manager)
            .ExecuteAsync();
```

And below is my code for GetAppTokenAsync() :

```
private static async Task<string> GetAppTokenAsync()
        {
            // Instantiate an AuthenticationContext for my directory (see authString above).
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authString, false);

            // Create a ClientCredential that will be used for authentication.
            // This is where the Client ID and Key/Secret from the Azure Management Portal is used.
            ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret);

            // Acquire an access token from Azure AD to access the Azure AD Graph (the resource)
            // using the Client ID and Key/Secret as credentials.
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resAzureGraphAPI, clientCred);

            // Return the access token.            
            return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code "await GetAppTokenAsync()" , you are getting an app-only token , which using application identity, instead of as a user's identity . 
The "(User)await adClient.Me" won't work if that token is not associated with a user .

To use app token to get user manager information ,you need to specify the user you want to query , code below is for your reference :

```
            try
            {
                User manager = (User)await adClient.Users.GetByObjectId("5eba8883-c258-45d0-8add-a286a1ec1e91").Manager.ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
```

**Update**

You could use [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) for delegated permissions(user's identity) . If you want a client library code sample , you could refer to [this code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web) . After user sign in , you could use below code to get manager of current login user :

```
            ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
            User manager = (User)await client.Me.Manager.ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you for your info, but unfortunately i've tried Googling and unable to find a clear answer on how I can get a User Identity token instead of an app token.
Can you give me some suggestions ?
I've edited my question above to include the code i'm using for GetAppTokenAsync().
TQ :)

Comment: I tried the above suggestion, but it requires admin privileges to run.
I've currently only assigned the "Sign in and read user profile" authorization to the app, as I only need to read the current logged-in user's profile information.

Comment: @DurairajVeeraSinnaiah ,please refer to my updated answer .

Comment: @DurairajVeeraSinnaiah  , any update ?  Please feel free to let me know if you have any problem to make the code sample work .

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply.
I still got the same error message :   
{"odata.error":{"code":"Request_ResourceNotFound","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Resource not found for the segment 'me'."}}}

I'm suspecting it could be due to the authorization given to the App registered in Azure AD, which is currently only give the following authorization :
"Sign in and read user profile"

I thought this permission should be sufficient for a user to get his/her own AD info, but seems not to be the case.
Could this be a reason ?

Comment: I have anyway requested the Admin to add the "Read directory data" permission to this app, and waiting to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: so now you are using app identity or user identity?

Answer (score 0):

I used an application identity with the *legacy* Azure Active Directory api and the 'Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy' permission to work around the `Resource not found for the segment 'me'` error. The same permission exists in the Microsoft Graph api, but the behavior is not identical. [More information here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/3215#issuecomment-456092466).